# Join issue for two tables

Tags: php, join, pdo

I can not get Select to work properly. I'm fairly familiar putting img src and have used loops before but the select is stumping me.

I have two tables. TableA (Aid, Aname, Adescription) TableB (Bid, Bimagefile, Aid). TableB holds multiple images which belong to TableA Aid. There may be 5 images for one Aid and 3 images for another Aid.

How can I write the Select and Join so I only see images related to 1 TableA Aid? I have the following

```
$query = "SELECT TableB.Bid, TableB.Bimagefile, TableA.Aname
FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.Aid = TableA.Aid";
```

but the results are a complete list of all Aname and their matching Bimagefile. I need to have the result show for one Aid. Help please.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
if($num>0){
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-         
bordered'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Image</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$Aname}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$Bimagefile}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: it's impossible to get just a single row from TableA, it will be always duplicated. You've got to group the data in PHP. See the solution [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/nested_array)

Comment: I don't know nested arrays at all. Is there an easier way to maybe group Bimagefile using Aid and then displaying the results? Or eliminating other Aid(s) to show results for one?